# CentOS 7 sudo >> -E: command not found

Tags: centos7, sudo

I'm working on CentOS 7 and regular sudo commands (e.g. sudo yum update, etc.) are working fine. However, one of my sudo commands require to preserve the environment variables, so I used:

```
sudo -E ./build/unit-tests
```

and I get this error:

```
/var/tmp/sclyZMkcN: line 8: -E: command not found
```

It appears sudo is not recognizing the -E command on CentOS 7. What can I do in this case? Any alternatives or possible fix?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I you know which variables to preserve, you can use `env` to pass them through the command line.

```
sudo env foo="$foo" bar="$bar" ./build/unit-tests
```

Comment: Thanks. this indeed is helpful. However, in case I don't know which vars to preserve and just want to preserve all, what would be the correct way? Also, is there a way to 'actually' know which vars are associated and how to pull them?

Comment: Ideally, `build/unit-tests` should have documentation which explains what variables it depends on. Commonly `HOME` and `USER` and `PATH` and anything for your particular platform environment (`JAVA_HOME` and `JAVA_PATH` for Java; `PYTHONPATH` for Python; `PERL5LIB` for Perl; etc) has significance. Your locale settings `LC_ALL`, `LANG`, `LC_COLLATE` etc might also affect some commands.

Comment: In the worst case, `set >file` and write a wrapper which sources back everything from this file; but some of the output will be specific to your current session (authentication tokens, terminal display size, etc).

Answer (score 3):

I've recently come across exactly the same problem. I tried to execute a script with `sudo -E`, which caused the above-mentioned `-E: command not found` error.

The reason turned out to be Red Hat Developer Toolset providing a broken `sudo`. A solution is to use the full `sudo` system path to make sure a good one is used, i.e.

`/usr/bin/sudo -E ./some_script.sh`

Comment: Thanks! This saved my day! These tools are also known as Software Collections.